# Which Seam Context To Use For A Overview Page With Filters (State)

Tags: java, scope, seam

I have a overview page containing a list with some links from which multiple workflows can be started (seam conversations).

The overview page also has some filters that can be used to search the list. Therefore I would like to keep state (for the filters) on the serverside.

At the moment this overview page uses a context of type Seam.CONVERSATION to achieve this. But each time I start one of these workflows, I have to make a workaround to start a new conversation (using the same conversation is not possible).

- Is there a pattern to solve this using the seam framework?
- Shall I use the PAGE scope and pass all the filter parameters together with the url's, old school style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversation scope sounds right. What's the problem with starting a new conversation? Perhaps you should focus on tidying up that work-around rather than changing scope. There are many built-in ways to start new conversations.

You could go the other way and use Session scope - I think the booking example does it this way (for a straight search rather than filters) and I've used it myself for a similar purpose.

Comment: Thanks, solved it with the session scope. However this brings in the problem that you can not have individual "workflows" in different browsers (that share the same session, obviously).

Comment: As I said, focusing on finding more convenient ways to trigger the new conversation would be the better approach, imho.

Answer (score 0):

The PAGE context seems like to right answer. But I'm unclear as to why this means you'd have to pass the filter parameters in manually.